# L'expression "c'est bibi"

Tags: expressions, histoire, origine-ou-raison, surnoms

En lisant le livre de Sylvie Weil *Chez les Weil* je suis tombé sur la citation suivante

> En ville on s'amuse beaucoup des airs de ma sœur quand elle va
>   faire des courses. On la considère, c'est elle qui le prétend, comme
>   une jeune femme sortant avec son mari. Le mari c'est Bibi !

C'est tiré d'une lettre de son grand oncle écrite en 1893. J'étais assez étonné de lire ça car j'avais toujours imaginé que l'expression « c'est bibi » appartenait à l'argot moderne. Je me suis donc demandé d'où venait cette expression mais n'ai rien trouvé sur le net (!!). Comme le grand oncle en question était juif je me suis demandé si ça venait de là mais je n'ai rien trouvé non plus dans cette direction.

Donc si quelqu'un a une explication sur l'origine de cette expression je serais ravi de l'entendre.

Comment: Le [TLF](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/bibi) cite des exemples des années 1870. Il n'y a pas d'étymologie précise, mais c'était déjà avant un surnom affectueux.

Comment: Je suis pas sur d'avoir compris. Ici c'est bien le frère qui réfère à lui même par l'expression Bibi. Le but de ma question est de comprendre l'origine de celle ci.

Comment: @ortholle *Je corrige mon commentaire* - J'opterais pour l'entrée du petit Robert : Bibi = moi (et non pas *Le mari c'est celui que sa sœur appelle Bibi*).

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Bibi est un mot arabe emprunté par la langue francaise qui veut dire "moi"

Comment: Considérant que le TLFi n'indique pas une étymologie arabe, ce serait intéressant d'avoir une source pour cette affirmation.

Comment: Ne veut-il pas dire aussi **dinde** ? Cf. : http://www.yabiladi.com/forum/d-ou-vient-bibi-6-3307441.html parmi les réponses

Comment: @ortholle : Oui, "c'est Bibi", çà veut dire "c'est moi"

Comment: J'avoue qu'une source serait pas mal :) mais merci d'avoir répondu.

Comment: bonjour je parle courament arabe et "bibi" ne veut rien dire en arabe. Cela ne veut certainement dire "moi", (en arabe, moi=ana).
Mais peut être ça vient de "Habibi" (c'est le seul rapprochement que je trouve).
Habib=Chéri, d'où Habibi=Mon chéri

Answer (score 7):

Le [CNRTL](http://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/bibi) indique que "bibi" était  utilisé dès 1765 comme un terme d'affection. D'après le [wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/bibi) son origine provient du radical "bib" signifiant "menue chose". Sa première utilisation dans la littérature avec le sens de "moi" est attribué à André Gill dans un poème publié dans [La Petite lune](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/La_Petite_Lune) (Disponible par la suite dans un recueil : *[La Muse à Bibi](https://books.google.fr/books?id=xsBXQwAACAAJ&dq=bibi+andr%C3%A9&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiAhY73hYfMAhVIXBoKHWoJDVEQ6AEIIDAA)*).

Sa signification de "moi" semble avoir une origine dans l'argot des enfants parisiens. D'après *[Le langage parisien au 19e siecle: facteurs sociaux, contingents linguistiques, faits sémantiques, influences littéraires](https://archive.org/stream/lelangageparisie00sainuoft/lelangageparisie00sainuoft_djvu.txt)* de Lazar Saineanu :

> Bibi est le substitut enfantin du pronom de la première 
>   personne : ça c'est pour bibi et bibi c'est moi. C'est en même 
>   temps un nom caressant que l'on donne aux enfants, impliquant la notion de petit [...].

Je penses qu'on peut en déduire que des enfants parisiens on commencé à se désigner par le terme bibi (de manière humoristique) puisque leur entourage les appelaient bibi de manière affectueuse.

D'après *[Les sources indigènes de l'étymologie française, Volumes 1-2](https://books.google.fr/books?id=XlQvAQAAIAAJ&q=bibi+%C3%A9tymologie&dq=bibi+%C3%A9tymologie&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi-_NGE_4bMAhUFChoKHRFdD_AQ6AEIMzAD)* de Lazăr Șăineanu le terme s'est ensuite propagé aux adultes :

> 1. Terme d'amitié donnée aux petits enfants et aussi aux animaux, chevreaux, chevaux, etc.
> 2. Moi dans le vulgaire parisien, mot passé des enfants¹ aux adultes

Il serait intéressant de consulter la note de bas de page, mais je n'ai pas réussi à y accéder.

Comment: Bien intéressant, _DHLF_ indique d'abord 1765 comme nom propre. Merci !