# Comment traduire « me, myself, and I » / How to translate "me, myself, and I"

Tags: traduction, anglais, pronoms, humour

Je recherche une traduction de la phrase « me, myself, and I » d'anglais à français.

I am looking for a translation of the phrase "me, myself, and I" from English to French.

Comment: 'I' can be 'Je' as well as 'Moi' in french, it depends on the context. I will eat => JE vais manger. You and I => Toi et MOI. You can usually translate myself by 'moi-même' so your phrase could be 'moi, moi, et moi' or 'moi, moi-même, and je' if you make a literal translation (:

Comment: Can you explain further this expression? This idiom has no obvious translation as far as i tried.

Comment: @Charly Would [this](http://www.yourdictionary.com/me-myself-and-i) help?

Comment: @Charly I saw it in a show called "Jokers" on MTV. This is a person doing a speech about himself, about his life in front of other people... It can be a book to (autobiography)... And "Me, myself and I" is the title of the book or the oral presentation...

Comment: Thanks, it does. Regarding to this, Laure's answer seems to be the best.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's a set phrase that won't translate literally into French. What we would you use in French much depends on the context of the whole sentence.

**Moi, et moi seul(e).**

> Cela suppose que le lecteur unique, complètement étranger à l'univers où mon livre va l'entraîner, dispose pourtant d'une capacité innée à me comprendre, **moi, et moi seul**. (Bernard Pingaud, *Mon roman et moi*)
>
> [Le diable voulait que je suive sa trace — moi, et moi seul. Et il m'attendait, quelque part dans une vallée du Jura](http://bit.ly/2a6q5H5).

**Moi et moi tout(e) seul(e)**.

> [J'ai beau me dire que l'idée venait du président Lincoln, la déculottée c'est moi, et moi tout seul, qui l'ai prise](http://bit.ly/2aiNQ1U),
>
> [Merci qui ? Merci moi. C'est moi et moi toute seule. Même pour Claire, même pour Richard, c'est moi qui l'ai fait, moi, toute seule](http://bit.ly/2a1x48M).

**Moi et rien que moi** is often used in personal blogs.

How would I translate it in  [Billie Holiday's song](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cMrS9_4XyYI) ?

> Moi et moi seule.

Same in [Beyoncé's](http://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/beyonceknowles/memyselfi.html).

But if I were to translate the [title of this book](http://bit.ly/2ajsSNy), I would have to go into something else altogether, digging into [the meaning of the book](http://bit.ly/2awviMa). I might end up with something like :

> Moi, ma conscience et moi-même.

But it's context dependent and there is not one translation, it will have to be adapted.

I've just checked about [Edward Albee](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edward_Albee)'s play: *Me Myself and I*, which hasn't been shown in France yet (at least to my knowledge) but has been in Québec and the French version is known as *Auditions ou Me, myself and I*.

Comment: +1 Moi et moi seul

Comment: Personnaly, I would say "Moi, ma conscience et moi-même." :)

Answer (score 4):

At the end of a sentence you could use:

> moi, moi-même et moi donc.

Or the more repetitive:

> moi, moi, moi et re-moi.
>
> moi, moi et encore moi.

At the beginning of a sentence, it's a little more problematic. Although for example this seems possible, but it's certainly not a common expression.

> Moi, moi-même et ma personne, avons unanimement décidé que…

You could also think of funny phrasings such as:

> En concertation avec moi-même, je choisis de …

Comment: "Moi, moi-même et ma personne" is also a funny phrasing.

Comment: Je déclare à l’unanimité que ça doit bien valoir +1.

Answer (score 2):

This does not translate well in french. Literraly it's "moi, moi même et je" but it sound very wrong.

This is in no way idiomatic but you could try :

- **Moi, moi, MOI !**
- **Moi, moi même, et ma conscience**
- **Moi, ma conscience et [bibi](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/8056/lexpression-cest-bibi)**.

All in all, "**Moi seul**" is the most idiomatic answer.

Answer (score 1):

As Jylo noted, there doesn't seem to be a good, literal or canonical translation in French. I would propose the following, which has a similar meaning but a different structure :

> *Seul(e) avec moi-même*